# Prove that any set of 2015 numbers has a subset who's sum is divisible by 2015

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I assume this is correct to any size set, not 2015 in particular... it's obviously true for 2. I know from pen and paper it's true for 3, and 4....

I understand that I should look at the reminders, and build pigeonholes from them. 
If one of the numbers has a 0 reminder obviously the entire set is divisible,
so the possible reminders go from 1 to (n-1). i have n numbers hence one of the reminders repeats. the sums of the reminders go from 1 to n*(n-1)....

And that's it...

Any and all help would be appreciated.

---

Of course I mean non empty set...

Comment: You probably mean "non-empty subset". Any set of numbers of any size has the empty set as a subset, which has a sum of zero, which is divisible by 2015.

Comment: @hvd off course

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let the set be $\{a_1,a_2\dots a_{2015}\}$

consider the sets $\{a_1\},\{a_1,a_2\},\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}\dots \{a_1,a_2\dots a_{2015}\}$

If one is a multiple of $2015$ we are done, if not two must have the same congruence, suppose $\{a_1,a_2\dots a_j\}$ and $\{a_1,a_2\dots a_h\}$ have the same congruence with $h<j$, then the set $\{a_{j+1},a_{j+2}\dots a_{h}\}$ has a sum that is multiple of $2015$.

The reason we took those sets is that they are a chain under inclusion, so we can subtract one from the other.

Comment: You really should complete your answer. For one, you didn't put any "Hint" disclaimer, so this is definitely incomplete.

Comment: can you explain what does congruence means?

Comment: It means they leave the same remainder when you divide by 2015

Comment: Cool.... such a simple answer... I've been working on it for the last couple of hours...

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Look at $a,a+b,a+b+c,a+b+c+d,...$