# Are the reminders of a set's elements modulo the cardinal all equal when none of the subset's sums is divisible by the cardinal?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have a set, I know it has a subset whose sum is divisible by the original set's cardinal. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118148/prove-that-any-set-of-2015-numbers-has-a-subset-whos-sum-is-divisible-by-2015))

If I have a set where none of its proper subsets' sums is divisible by the original set's cardinal, does all of the original set's elements have the same reminder modulo the original set's cardinal?

Comment: What?  If you know that there must be sub-set divisible by the cardinal then you know that having a set where none of the proper sub-set's sum is divisible by the cardinal is impossible.

Comment: @fleablood That's not true - the subset in question might not be proper. Take $\{1, 1\}$.

Comment: 2, 5, 8 more characters

Comment: Anyone? More characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that all numbers in the set are congruent modulo the cardinality of the set.

Denote the set by $S$ and suppose $|S| = n \geqslant 2$. If $n = 2$, suppose $S = \{a, b\}$, then $2 \not\mid a$, $2 \not\mid b$ implies $a \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.

For $n \geqslant 3$, if $a, b \in S$ satisfy $a \not\equiv b \pmod{n}$, suppose $S = \{a, b, c_1, \cdots, c_{n - 2}\}$. Now consider the following $n$ proper subsets:$$
\{a\}, \{b\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, c_1\}, \cdots, \{a, b, c_1, \cdots, c_{n - 3}\}.
$$
Because for any of these sets, $n$ does not divide the sum of its elements, by the pigeonhole principle, there are two sets $A$ and $B$ such that the sum of $A$'s elements is congruent to that of $B$'s. Note that if $A = \{a\}$, then $B \neq \{b\}$, and if $A = \{b\}$, then $B \neq \{a\}$, therefore either $A$ and $B$ are in this chain:$$
\{a\} \subset \{a, b\} \subset \{a, b, c_1\} \subset \cdots \subset \{a, b, c_1, \cdots, c_{n - 3}\},
$$
or in this chain:$$
\{b\} \subset \{a, b\} \subset \{a, b, c_1\} \subset \cdots \subset \{a, b, c_1, \cdots, c_{n - 3}\}.
$$
Without loss of generality, suppose $A \subset B$, then $B \setminus A$ is a non-empty proper set of $S$ but $n$ divides the sum of the elements of $B \setminus A$, a contradiction.

Therefore, all elements in $S$ are congruent modulo $|S|$.